# Is there any Gerrit client for Windows?

Tags: gerrit

Is there any Gerrit client for Winodws? I am looking for a client rather than using a Web UI. The Old web UI is not very intuitive and the new web UI (PolyGerrit) lacks lot of functionalities from the Old UI.
So I am looking for a Client for windows where I can configure the UI and functionalities.

Comment: *"the new web UI (PolyGerrit) lacks lot of functionalities from the Old UI"* is not very accurate for recent stable version, I suggest to upgrade to latest stable, which does not have the old GWT UI any longer! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a **GUI** app with *all* the capabilities you can do from the Web UI. Here are some pointers, though:

- [IntelliJ Gerrit plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7272-gerrit), in case you're using any of the IntelliJ IDEs this may be very much providing you the daily reviewing tasks.
- CollabNet offers a commercial/shareware Git Client with Gerrit Code Review integration: [GitEye](https://www.collab.net/products/giteye).
- An open source Python-powered *console* application [gertty](https://opendev.org/ttygroup/gertty) made by the authors of OpenStack.